# iPhone color picker

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I'm trying to build a color picker view on the iPhone. I want to draw one of those 'color maps' and let the user tap on the color. I can create a gradient (in the X axis) ok which gives me the color range, but I also want to combine the lightness (in the Y axis) which is where I'm struggling.

Any help would be most welcome.

Thanks

PS: I've seen the example at http://www.v-vent.com/blog/?p=27 but this uses a colormap png file which is not very 'smooth'.

Answer (score 1):

Try working with the [HSV or HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color spaces. You can have the value/lightness or saturation on the Y axis.

Comment: In Apple's HSV color picker on the Mac, the angle is hue, radius is saturation, and a separate slider is brightness (value).

Comment: Yeah - I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to actually draw this. Looking at the CGGradient code there are only 2 options (linear and radial) I guess what I want is a 2D gradient.

Comment: Radial would work. You'd need at least four points in the gradient: One of the primary colors at each “end”, and the other two at the one-third and two-thirds points.

Answer (score 0):

The [BNColor](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=100) class might be useful for you.  This includes conversions between HSV and RGB, among other features.